# Intent function while running application get crashed

Tags: validation, firebase, android-intent, firebase-authentication

When clicked on this textview the app get crashed and didn't change the activity it is suppose to switch from main activity to another how to resolve it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etPassword;
private TextView tvLogin;
private TextView tvSignup;
private Button btnSignin, btMr;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);

    updateUI();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}

private void updateUI() {
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    tvSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSignup);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    tvLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLogin);
    btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    tvSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signup();
        }
        public void signup() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Here I used awesome validation for validating my form but while running the app shows the toast message, but do not register the user to fire base it validate my form but do not register

```
    String regexPassword = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[~`!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\+=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\;:\"<>,./\\?]).{8,}";
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(MainActivity.this, R.id.etEmail, android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.etEmailerr);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation(MainActivity.this, R.id.etPassword, regexPassword, R.string.etPasserr);

    btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Recieved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    });
}
```

This part register the user to firebase, but after adding this awesome validation this do not work app shows a toast message from validation and do not register or change activity how can i merge both so that my form get validate and also get register to my firebase auth

```
public void btnLogin_Click(View v) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait....", "Processing...", true);

    (firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString()))
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOGIN SUCCESSFULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent signin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(signin);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to the regex function.
the values used in activity1 regex get differ in another activity2 due to which the intent can't switch from one activity to another.
values passed the the regex should be same in all the activity linked.